# Extending the range of wireless-extender

Tags: discussion, tag-synonym-request

Is it possible to get the tag [range-extender](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/range-extender) converted to a synonym of [wireless-extender](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/wireless-extender)?

The questions in each category seem to be talking about extending the range of wireless signals.

What does everyone think to this idea?

Comment: I thought this was a question for superuser.com itself until I saw the detail of this question - nice trick ;)

Comment: looks good, though I think I will leave the actual post and implimentation to when I have had enough sleep

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Seems reasonable. It's done.

I've merged and synonymized them, though the lack of tag wiki content both made this painless and made me sad.

Comment: I'll get right on that boss!